# Why was there so much talking about meeting with the Russian ambassador in the Oval Office?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump

I am aware of the controversy between the Trump Administration's potential ties with Russia, but people seem to be concerned specifically over the fact that the meeting occurred in the Oval Office.

Since the Oval Office is the official office of the POTUS, it's not unreasonable to assume that it is a reasonable place to meet with foreign dignitaries or ambassadors.

What is interesting about the fact that the meeting occurred in the Oval Office as opposed to some other place?

Comment: Why do you think they were specifically concerned with the venue of the meeting? From [what I read](https://www.washingtonpost.com/world/national-security/trump-revealed-highly-classified-information-to-russian-foreign-minister-and-ambassador/2017/05/15/530c172a-3960-11e7-9e48-c4f199710b69_story.html?utm_term=.8c048c460224) they are mostly concerned with the person (Russian ambassador and his previous position in Russian intelligence) and the contents of the meeting (the disclosure of classified material).

Answer (score 6):

I would not agree that the major concerns were the location of the meeting, but rather:

- the timing, (a day after Trump fired the FBI Director)
- the composition of the attendees, (the ambassador's under suspicion of a role in Russian interference in the 2016 elections, with a Russian press photographer present yet [the US press wasn't invited](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/05/10/us/politics/trump-russia-meeting-american-reporters-blocked.html)),
- Trump's [disclosure of intelligence information](https://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/inside-the-oval-office-with-trump-and-the-russians-broad-smiles-and-loose-lips/2017/05/16/2e8b0d14-3a66-11e7-8854-21f359183e8c_story.html?utm_term=.1a3b77b1df06).

I checked my memory that there was also a concern about only having a Russian translator but that was only raised regarding the Putin-Trump meeting.

Comment: [Plus](https://www.wired.com/2017/05/russian-photographer-oval-office-bug/) "The White House says it didn't realize the government photographer who accompanied Lavrov to the meeting was also a journalist; it had barred US media from the meeting" -- after which at which there was comment that they *ought* to know who's visiting the Oval office.